# Issue with excluding object from post-processing in VR

Tags: unity, camera, virtual-reality, post-processing

I wanted to exclude some objects from a specific layer from rendering in the post processing.

I followed both : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAopDQDCwak and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AooFfmQ_Svo&t=290s But it appears that in VR the rendering of the second camera (both tutorials above use a second camera) doesn't appear. The objects show when I change the depth of the second camera but they appear above everything. I'm using the built-in rendering.

Any Idea how to prevent it ?

Comment: Can you specify what post-processing effects you want to apply selectively like this? For some effects, we might be able to use the stencil buffer to mask out pixels to prevent them from being touched by the post process, without camera stacking. But for other effects, that won't be a practical solution and we'd need to investigate other options.

Comment: I use custom post processing found online https://github.com/Ooseykins/QuickDither. But I also tried the built-in colorgrading and got the same issue